# Php query from url

Tags: php

I'm sure this has been answered on stack before but I don't know the proper terms to use to find my desired results.

I want to take a value in a url and input it into my php script. So if I goto:

`http://mydomain/search.php='MYSEARCHQUERY'`

The search.php would take the `MYSEARCHQUERY` as a value.

```
<?php 
$html=file_get_contents('http://anotherwebsite/MYSEARCHQUERY'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL would be something like:

```
http://mydomain/search.php?query=MYSEARCHQUERY
```

and the PHP:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://anotherwebsite/' . $_GET['query']);
```

Comment: Was about to downvote, but your edit was quickly pushed to my browser. +1 where it's deserved